# Password Confirmation Fields with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, nhibernate-mapping, fluent

I'm new to NHibernate and am trying to build my first simple website. I want a user registration screen with Password and ConfirmPassword fields.

I have these fields in my `User` business object, but am having trouble working out which mapping to use so that the `ConfirmPassword` field is loaded from the `Password` database field when a `User` is loaded, but ignored when the object is saved.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say its not the best way to go. Rather create two classes. One is User - entity from domain, one is UserViewModel - usually plain DTO. When saving or retrieving User object map its values to ViewModel. You can do in manually or use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) library. So User has only Password, and ViewModel has both properties.

But if you need this or something similar, in your mapping write

```
mapping.Map(o => o.PasswordConfirm).Formula(" Password ");
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your answer makes sense, but what it you wanted to pass the Domain object straight to the view? Is what I want to do possible simply using NHibernate?

Comment: P.S. I'm sure there are other situations where the same technique is required, so can we think about this from an academic point of view?